# Mysql inner join and rounding with null precision

Tags: mysql, rounding

I am attempting to perform an inner join on two tables so that I can round a value by the precision associated with that value's pid in the other table. However, it is returning NULL for pid 3. I believe it has to do with the NULL precision for pid 2, because when I set it's precision to a non-NULL value, I get the correct value for pid 3 in the query below.

How can I restructure this query so that it will always return the correct value even if another pid contains a NULL precision?

```
select pid_values.pid, pid_values.value, round(value, pids.precision) 
from pid_values inner join pids on pid_values.pid = pids.pid;

+------+--------+------------------------------+
| pid  | value  | round(value, pids.precision) |
+------+--------+------------------------------+
|    1 | 10.123 |                           10 |
|    2 |    5.5 |                            6 |
|    3 | 3.1234 |                         NULL |
+------+--------+------------------------------+
```

Data in both tables:

```
select * from pids;
+------+-----------+
| pid  | precision |
+------+-----------+
|    1 |         0 |
|    2 |      NULL |
|    3 |         1 |
+------+-----------+

select * from pid_values
+----+------+--------+
| id | pid  | value  |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 |    1 | 10.123 |
|  2 |    2 |    5.5 |
|  3 |    3 | 3.1234 |
+----+------+--------+
```

Comment: Sounds more like a bug in MySQL... (Also fwiw, I'd actually expect the one with pid = 2 to return null, based on the idea that round() should return null on null input.)

Comment: Actually, it appears that once you passed `NULL` as `D` to `ROUND`, all subsequent calls to `ROUND` (in that query) return `NULL`.

Comment: So, the question is: what do you want it to return when `precision IS NULL`? `NULL`, the amount rounded to 0, or `0`?

Comment: See MySQL bugs [55423](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55423) and [55365](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55365).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
  pid_values.pid, 
  pid_values.value, 
  round(value, IF(pids.precision IS NULL, 0, pids.precision)) 
FROM pid_values INNER JOIN pids ON pid_values.pid = pids.pid;
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass NULL to round. Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
 pid_values.pid, 
 pid_values.value, 
 if( pids.precision IS NULL , NULL , round( value, pids.precision ) ) 
FROM pid_values
INNER JOIN pids 
ON pid_values.pid = pids.pid;
```

[Hck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201375/mysql-inner-join-and-rounding-with-null-precision/6201426#6201426) seems to have had the same idea as me, but the implementations differ. When `precision IS NULL` , I'll have the result return `NULL` (as in your example, and to differ from `precision =0`), while he'll round to an integer instead. Choose whatever suits your needs best.